# Spark.sql : Remove table's name on columns name

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

when I query my database as :

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM MyBase")
```

I have "MyBase." in front of all my column's name.

Can we simply avoid that ? If not, what is the best way to remove it ?

Example :

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT name, price FROM MyBase")
df.show(2)

+-------------+--------------+
| mybase.name | mybase.price |
+-------------+--------------+
|    Jean     |     15.0     |
|    Phil     |     10.0     |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I just want name and price as column name.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain your problem with some sample i/p & o/p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing new set of columns to your `dataframe` by removing the prefix name upto `.`. Here is a sample solution which will work for all columns.

```
data = [(1,2,3), (11,22,33)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data,['a.a','a.b','a.c'])
df1.show()
"""
+---+---+---+
|a.a|a.b|a.c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
| 11| 22| 33|
+---+---+---+
"""


new_cols = [i[i.find('.')+1:] for i in df1.columns]
df2 = df1.toDF(*new_cols)
df2.show()
"""
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
| 11| 22| 33|
+---+---+---+
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you set the option

```
hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=true
```

for somewhere in your hive-site.xml or on the spark session. It should be `false` for your purpose.

Comment: Can we change this parameter directly in the definiton of sparkContext or SparkSession or other ?

Comment: Try `spark.sql("set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false")` and do your step.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [(1,2,3), (11,22,33)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data,['a.a','a.b','a.c'])
cols = [x.split('.')[1] for x in df1.columns]
display(df1.toDF(*cols))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is recommended to add some explanation to the answers. Code-only answers may be confusing.